Print macro in \addplot node label
I use a foreach loop to plot multiple curves via the \addplot command. The values that are necessary to define the relevant curve in each iteration are defined through some macros with the command \def. Each curve is also associated to a node text label that is supposed to show the value of a given macro at each iteration.
I manage to plot the curves correctly, whereas the node text label does not print out or it prints out some wrong number.
I have tried multiple possible solutions among the relatively few encountered online. However, I have not found a solution to this problem, which is almost certainly due to some parsing issue that I am unable to spot and resolve.
Please, find attached the minimum executable code to reproduce the image hereby. I would need the label to show the value of \YA in the equation $Y=\YA$.
\documentclass[lulatex,beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
    
% Define parameters
\def\gammaA{0.5}
\def\gammaB{0.5}
\def\L{4}
\def\K{4}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
restrict x to domain=0:\L,
restrict y to domain=0:\K,
xmin = 0, xmax = \L,
ymin = 0, ymax = \K,
xlabel = {$L$},
ylabel = {$K$}
]

% Draw level curves
\foreach \i in {0.25, 0.5}{
    
    % Define variables as a function of \i
    \def\LA{\i*\L};
    \def\KA{(\gammaA*(1-\gammaB)*\K*\LA)/((1-\gammaA)*\gammaB*(\L-\LA)+\gammaA*(1-\gammaB)*\LA)};
    \def\YA{((\LA)^(1-\gammaA)*((\KA)^\gammaA)};
    
    % Plot for each \i
    \addplot [very thick, mark=none] {(\YA/(\x^(1-\gammaA)))^(1/\gammaA)} node [anchor=center, pos=0.8, fill=white, rounded corners=4pt, inner sep=1pt] {$Y=\YA$};
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Loop in an axis requires a different approach.

Sure, that's why I asked for help. So, what is the different approach that would allow me to do what I want to do?

take a look at this post

I had already seen that and similar posts. Generally, they all deal with passing on the iteration variable (or some function thereof) as an argument to the coordinates command. But this is not what I need, and that is why I posted a minimum working example. So that any answer could move from there on.

The problem is that nodes are drawn after the plot, when the command \YA is no more defined.
You can play with expansion and define a command the draw the graph. Something like:
\edef\plotcommand
  {%
    \noexpand\addplot [very thick, mark=none]
    {(\YA/(\noexpand\x^(1-\gammaA)))^(1/\gammaA)}
    node [anchor=center, pos=0.8, fill=white, rounded corners=4pt, inner sep=1pt]
    {$Y=\YA$};
  }

Here \edef expands the definition before setting the command and \noexpand prevent the expansion of \addplot and \x. Replace then the \addplot command with \plotcommand.
By the way, I assume you're looking for the numerical value of the parameters, not their formulas. Replace \def with \pgfmathsetmacro in the computation:
\pgfmathsetmacro{\LA}{\i*\L};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\KA}{(\gammaA*(1-\gammaB)*\K*\LA)/((1-\gammaA)*\gammaB*(\L-\LA)+\gammaA*(1-\gammaB)*\LA)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YA}{((\LA)^(1-\gammaA)*((\KA)^\gammaA))};

Complete example:
\documentclass[lulatex,beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}

% Define parameters
\def\gammaA{0.5}
\def\gammaB{0.5}
\def\L{4}
\def\K{4}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
restrict x to domain=0:\L,
restrict y to domain=0:\K,
xmin = 0, xmax = \L,
ymin = 0, ymax = \K,
xlabel = {$L$},
ylabel = {$K$}
]

% Draw level curves
\foreach \i in {0.25, 0.5}{

    % Define variables as a function of \i
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\LA}{\i*\L};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\KA}{(\gammaA*(1-\gammaB)*\K*\LA)/((1-\gammaA)*\gammaB*(\L-\LA)+\gammaA*(1-\gammaB)*\LA)};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\YA}{((\LA)^(1-\gammaA)*((\KA)^\gammaA))};

    % Plot for each \i
    \edef\plotcommand
    {%
      \noexpand\addplot [very thick, mark=none]
      {(\YA/(\noexpand\x^(1-\gammaA)))^(1/\gammaA)}
      node [anchor=center, pos=0.8, fill=white, rounded corners=4pt, inner sep=1pt]
      {$Y=\YA$};
    }
    \plotcommand
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Thank you for your very useful answer. I've noticed that I have a further need relative to my initial question: namely, I would need to contro the font size of the node label. I have tried the standard way, but I get an error. Do you know how I could add a command like '\tiny' to make the label smaller?

@LauraRoich You need to use \noexpand to protect \tiny from expansion at command definition. Edit your question, if needed.

Apparently, I cannot edit my post anymore. I am unable to say why exactly. So probably you could just write here in a comment how the protection is supposed to take place. Or, if you have privileges, you can directly edit my question. Sorry about this, and thanks again.

@LauraRoich \noexpand prevent the expansion of the following token. Try \noexpand\tiny in place of \tiny.

\noexpand\tiny works perfectly. Many thanks!
